# Difference in Permission Model Between SharePoint 2010, 2013 and 2016

Tags: 2013, 2010, permissions, 2016

Can anyone please point out the differences in Permission Model between SharePoint 2010, 2013 (including On Premise and Online) and 2016 versions, possibly with some authentic references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model hasn't changed since really at least 2007. Are you confusing Permissions Model with perhaps Authorization? From that perspective, nothing has changed since 2010.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Can you please elaborate the difference between Permission Model and Authorization? I am asking because you are saying that the model hasn't changed since 2007, whereas Authorization hasn't changed since 2010. Also, can you please post some links substantiating the same? I need to provide them to my customer.

Comment: As I just told you, there's no change. I'd suggest you demo it to your customer. Probably the best thing you can provide is Classic v. Claims authorization, both of which have been available since SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I will accept your reply, since it is coming from an MVP.